# ActionScript 2.0 Random Boolean Function not working

Tags: actionscript-2

I have the below code which show be randomly true and randomly false. But in my case its always being false. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

In the below code tail and heads are the tow buttons.

```
on(release)
{
    var guess:Boolean =  Boolean(Math.round(Math.random()));
    var input:Boolean;
    if (event.target.name == "tail"){
        input = true;
    }
    else if (event.target.name == "heads"){
        input = false;
    }
    if (guess == input){   
        var newresult = Number(income.text) + Number(amount.text);
        income.text = Number(newresult);
    }
    else{
        var newresult = Number(income.text) - Number(amount.text);
        income.text = Number(newresult);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it now a few times in AS2.0 and it gave random results.

Comment: `var i:Number;
for(i=0;i<20;i++){
var guess:Boolean =  Boolean(Math.round(Math.random()));
trace(guess);
}`

Comment: Please find the source file here http://therockstar.tk/game.fla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will also work:

```
on(release)
{
    var guess:Boolean = Boolean(Math.floor(Math.random()*2));
    if (guess){
    result.text = "Your Guess is corrent";
    var newresult = Number(income.text) + Number(amount.text);
    income.text = Number(newresult);
}
else{
    result.text = "Your Guess is wrong";
    var newresult = Number(income.text) - Number(amount.text);
    income.text = Number(newresult);
}
}
```

You dont need the event.target.name because the function is within the event handler of each button. So you can just use a random boolean. Event.target.name also doesnt work in AS2.0